# Data is not being displaying in tableview Swift CoreData

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to create an task app where, once i enter the data in the text field , it's not being showing the table view controller.

```
created data model : Logs
Table view identifier name : Cell
Entity name: Logs
Attribute name : desc



import UIKit
import CoreData

class firstPage : UITableViewController , NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var add: UIBarButtonItem!


    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchedResultController = getFetchedResultController()
        fetchedResultController.delegate = self
        do {
            try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
        } catch _ {
        }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "edit" {
            let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let taskController:secondPage = segue.destinationViewController as! secondPage
            let tsk:Logs = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Logs
            taskController.log = tsk
        }
    }

    // MARK:- Retrieve Tasks

    func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultController
    }

    func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Logs")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "desc", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return fetchRequest
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // MARK: - TableView data source


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        let numberOfSections = fetchedResultController.sections?.count
        return numberOfSections!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let numberOfRowsInSection = fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        return numberOfRowsInSection!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let tak = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Logs
        cell.textLabel?.text = tak.desc

        return cell
    }

}
```

I didn't get it why the data is not showing the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should confirm to `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`

And provide functions like this:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Update:
            self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject)
        case .Move:
            tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Here is sample code used by apple master detail template which you can compare:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.collapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
        let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context)

        // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
        // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
        newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")

        // Save the context.
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        self.configureCell(cell, withObject: object)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)

            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
    }

    // MARK: - Fetched results controller

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        do {
            try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
        } catch {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
             abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }    
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Update:
                self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject)
            case .Move:
                tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    /*
     // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

     func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
         // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
     */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After fetching the content through `NSFetchedResultsController`, you need to tell the UITableView to reload the data.

The Docs suggest to implement `controllerDidChangeContent:` of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` refresh the table view:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html